# 28.02.2018 перестала работать функция "Вставить результат вычисления формулы как значения"

Tags: google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Именно сегодня перестала работать функция - вставить результат вычисления формулы как значения. (В Google Apps Scripts, Google Spreadsheets). На сейчас эта функция работает как clearContents() - просто затирает все значения.

Пример:

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
  var range = sheet.getRange("A1:C3")
  range.setFormula("=1+2")

  range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true})
  //Или так:
  //range.copyValuesToRange(sheet, range.getColumn(), range.getLastColumn(), range.getRow(), range.getRowIndex())
  //range.copyTo(range, SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false)
}
```

Можно использовать другие методы, поколдовав с форматами, но почему же перестало работать??

```
range.setValue(range.getValues())
range.setValue(range.getDisplayValues())
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вдруг кому интересно будет не смотря на минусовой вопрос:

Необходимо добавить перед `range.copyTo(range, {contentsOnly:true})`  `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`

Согласно документации, этот метод применяет все ожидающие изменения в таблице

> Applies all pending Spreadsheet changes.

То есть, как я понимаю, ранее, при вызове copyTo, google перед тем, как брать данные из ячеек, сам применял все изменения (высчитывал результаты формул), а после этого уже делал копирование. Сейчас же нужно этот момент задавать вручную.

**UPD1:**
Согласно комментарию [oshliaer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178725/oshliaer), можно и Sheets API использовать.

Насколько я понимаю, код будет где-то такой:

```
// ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
// sheet = ss.getSheetByName("NAME")
//Для примера: range = sheet.getRange("A1:C")
function killAllFormulas2(ss, sheet, range) {
  // Обязателен вызов flush(), иначе если вы только вставили сложные формулы и сразу захотели вставить результаты вычисления как значения - они могут не успеть обновить данные в ячейках
  SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  // Получаем ID вашего Spreadsheet
  var ssID = ss.getId()
  // Если выбран такой диапазон как в примере - его обязательно нужно перевести в вид A1:C1000 (условно)
  var rangeA1 = sheet.getRange(range.getRow(), range.getColumn(), range.getLastRow()-range.getRow()+1, range.getLastColumn()-range.getColumn()+1).getA1Notation()
  // Получаем значения  
  var values = Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.get(ssID, sheet.getName() + "!" + rangeA1)
  // Вставляем значения
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.Values.update(values, ssID, sheet.getName() + "!" + rangeA1, {valueInputOption:"USER_ENTERED"})
 }
```

В примерах, которые встречаются вот [здесь](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values) указано, что для большинства случаев использования лучше использовать стандартные методы встроенного SpreadsheetApp (например цитата для записи данных:

> This code uses the Sheets Advanced Service, but for most use cases the built-in method SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(range).getValues(values) is more appropriate.

По скорости работы я проверял на некоторых диапазонах со сложными формулами - разницы вообще не увидел. Скорее всего это все один и тот же алгоритм.

Надеюсь, этот ответ поможет кому-то не тратить драгоценное время на поиски истины.

Comment: К сожалению, нет. `flush` требовался всегда, но его полезность, как видно, сомнительна. `copyTo`, как я понимаю, не самый удачный сахар над API `copyTo`. Если вы будете делать тоже самое через Advanced Services Sheet API, то такого не происходит. Я рекомендую использовать `copyTo` только в случаях, когда это действительно обосновано.

Comment: Соглашусь с выводами. Мое замечание касается только и именно `copyTo`. getValues <=> setValues должны работать лучше.

Comment: Спасибо большое, что помогли разобраться!

Comment: Добавил пример copyTo https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets#copyto

Comment: Единственный минус, который я заметил при копировании с помощью getValues/setValues - это форматы. То есть если до этой операции был общий формат и в нем была допустим дата, то она вставляется как число и отображается как число. То есть желательно формат указывать точный, а не общий

Comment: Можно поколдовать с Sheet API, а можно просто сделать override https://github.com/oshliaer/google-apps-script-snippets/issues/13 Только его еще сделать надо =)

Comment: А ведь больше года работал на 100% обычный copyTo  с contentsOnly:true. Ни разу не подводил и скорость отличная. Надо ж было туда влезть...Наверное одно исправили, второе недоисправили)